# Is there a formula to create universal coordinates for resolutions in Python?

Tags: python, screen

In autoit, the code is the below:

```
Func _ConvertXY(ByRef $Xin, ByRef $Yin)
    $Xin = Round(($Xin / 2560) * @DesktopWidth)
    $Yin = Round(($Yin / 1440) * @DesktopHeight)
EndFunc   ;==>_ConvertXY

$flashXa = 1059
$flashYa = 1285 ; Your intended coordinates on the original 2560x1440 desktop
_ConvertXY($flashXa, $flashYa) ; Convert proportionally to the actual desktop size
```

I'm trying to do the same thing but in Python - so basically it adjusts the coordinates to the screen size relative to a 1440p screen, irrespective of your resolution.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you need a function that for example, will convert the lower third of your screen from 1080p to 4k? So if the lower third is always at the same relative location? What kind of parameters would you want to pass to the function? Just x, y coordinates, the resolution to and from?

Comment: No, I'm trying to convert a set of coordinates for mouse movements in 1440p to work across all resolutions i.e. 1080p or a different resolution. So it wouldn't be specific to a section of the screen.

Comment: So you want just a function that will convert coordinates from one resolution to another?

Comment: Exactly - is it as simple as 
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

then taking the coordinate and dividing by 2560(x) or 1440(y) and multiplying by screen_width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I gather you're looking for:

```
def res_conv(x: int, y: int, resolution_from: tuple, resolution_to: tuple) -> tuple:
    assert x < resolution_from[0] and y < resolution_from[1], "Input coordinate is larger than resolution"
    x_ratio = resolution_to[0] / resolution_from[0] # ratio to multiply x co-ord
    y_ratio = resolution_to[1] / resolution_from[1] # ratio to multiply y co-ord
    return int(x * x_ratio), int(y * y_ratio)
```

Example:

```
res_conv(100, 100, (2560, 1440), (1920, 1080)
```

Will return:

```
(75, 75)
```